# Any good CDN integration with Drupal?

Tags: 7, cdn

I'd like to set up a simple gallery for users to upload pictures onto my D7 site, but uploading a bunch of images is sure to make my site run slower and my hosting costs go up. So I'm looking at a CDN (specifically, blob or object storage).

Both of the Azure modules ([1](https://drupal.org/project/azure_blob) and [2](https://drupal.org/project/azure)) are not actively maintained, and the [Amazon S3](https://drupal.org/project/amazons3) module is still in beta, so I'd be hesitant to use it on a production site.

Here's my question: Is there any good Druapl module that will let me bypass the filesystem on the webserver so that users can upload images directly to a CDN? I know there are hooks in D7 that make this possible, but has anyone actually managed to do it yet? I can't believe there isn't better support for CDNs for Drupal. :(

Comment: This was helpful for me http://cdnsun.com/knowledgebase/integrations/drupal-cdn-integration Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 has robust CDN integration with a number of options. You can consider the [Storage API](https://drupal.org/project/storage_api) module for S3 integration among others.

> Storage API is a low-level framework for managed file storage and serving.

Also consider the [CDN](https://drupal.org/project/cdn) module.

> This module provides easy Content Delivery Network integration for Drupal sites. It alters file URLs, so that files are downloaded from a CDN instead of your web server.

Comment: I was not aware that `Storage API` came bundled with an S3 provider. I'll give this a try. Thanks!